# Changing Gnome back to Unity

Tags: unity, gnome, session, 13.10

I recently installed the new Gnome 3.8 on my Ubuntu OS thinking it would only add the DE to my session manager at log in.  I was wrong however.  It actually changed the default to Gnome!  I prefer Unity much more, but cannot change it back.  How can I fix this?

Comment: So what do you see in your session manager? Usually you can select the DE from a drop-down list.

Comment: I see all the DE's in the session manager, but I can't figure out how to change the default DE so I can log in automatically.  The display manager is the GDM Gmome style as well; I want the LightDM style, that I misatakenly didn't choose upon installation.

Comment: I use lightDM too, although I think it's a KDE variant. In my system, `/etc/X11/default-display-manager` contains `/usr/sbin/lightdm`. I guess you can try changing this first, then see if your selection of DE sticks. I used gdm once, and I seem to recall that it automatically made the last-selected DE as the default for next time, but I guess not. See if lightDM does this, though.

Comment: Well, it's just me at the moment (not "you all"), but I'm not really sure how to help you with that problem, since I use KDE not Unity. I'd suggest creating a new question, and then trying this fix later when you have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

If the problem is the session manager, you can switch using the command:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm
```

A dialogue will appear where you can chose between GDM and Lightdm.

The process is better explained [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/07/how-to-switch-between-gdm-lightdm-or.html).